# disabling emails received by admins every time a new user signs up (function not working)

Tags: user-registration

I have the following function in my functions.php. I am trying to disable the admin from receiving emails every time a new user joins the site. However, the admin is still receiving emails. Is there something wrong with the function? And is this part of the WP options by any chance? I couldn't find the option anywhere.

```
// Disable New User Reg Emails
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_new_user_notification' ) ) :
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {

        /** Return early if no password is set */
        if ( empty( $plaintext_pass ) )
            return;

        $user       = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
        $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );

        // The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
        // we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES );

        $message  = sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login) . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __( 'Password: %s' ), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

        wp_mail( $user_email, sprintf( __( '[%s] Your username and password' ), $blogname ), $message );

    }
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your function earlier than you are. It seems that the "real" wp_new_user_notification() (from wp-includes/pluggable.php) is getting created before yours is. To test, remove the `if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_new_user_notification' ) ) :` from your code. You should be getting an error.

You could create a plugin:

```
//Plugin Name: blahblah
function wp_new_user_notification() {
  // your code
}
```

Alternatively, just put that code in it's own .php file and drop it in wp-content/mu-plugins directory (create if it doesn't exist). Problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that can handle disabling new user registrations: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-new-user-notifications/

Comment: Hi Chip, that's actually the plugin where I got the function from. I just stripped the function because I didn't want to add another plugin.

Comment: And you're using it directly in your `functions.php` for the theme you're using?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.